# Matching a Regular Expression pattern that may may repeat n times

Tags: java, regex

Requirement:
The string should be of the format:
import SOME_NAME = require("RELATIVE_PATH")
where RELATIVE_PATH should either start with ./ or ../ and should be in double quotes

Examples of valid strings:

> #### Test String1:
>
> import test = require("../../file3")
>   There should be a match
>
> #### Test String2:
>
> import test = require("./file3")
>   There should be a match

Examples of invalid string:

> #### Test String3:
>
> import test = require("file3")
>   This is invalid since the relative path did not start with either ./ or ../
>
> #### Test String4:
>
> import test = require('./file3')
>   This is invalid since the relative path should be in double quotes ""

**The REGEX that I am using to test the strings match the above pattern is**

```
final String REGEX = "import\\s\\w+\\s?=\\s?require\\(\\\"(./|../)[A-Za-z0-9]*\"\\)"
boolean isAMatch = testString.matches(REGEX);
```

The Regex fails to match on testString1 as Regex pattern does not handle strings with repeated pattern like ../../ or ././ in the relative path.

I tried modifying the REGEX like this  (./+|../+)

```
final String REGEX = "import\\s\\w+\\s?=\\s?require\\(\\\"(./+|../+)[A-Za-z0-9]*\"\\)"
```

but this did not work. What am i missing here ?

Comment: Frankly, I would look for some other approach. Regex doesn't seem like the ideal solution here.

Comment: I totally agree with @TheLostMind. Have a look `\s*import [^=]+=\s*require\("\.{1,2}\/[^"]+"\)`. [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pJ5hH3/1)

Comment: Thanks that works !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
^import\\s+\\w+\\s*=\\s*require\\("(?:\\.\\.?\\/)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+"\\)$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/3

Comment: the above regular expression will not work though if the relative path has whitespaces. example  **import test = require('./file   3') **this will be rejected